# Check if a process is running against a specified username on Remote computer (Vb .Net)

Tags: vb.net

Good Day All,

We have a component service which runs on remote domain computer. I am very much a newbie for this sort of Vb automation. Although I could not find a code to assist finding if the component service is runnning or not, I did notice that this particular Component Service runs as "dllhost.exe" process against a username which we specify under the Identity tab of Properties.

However, there may be other "dllhost.exe" processes running on same machine and hence I am looking for some sample VB Net code that will retun if my Component Service is Running or Not; by supplying the remote machine name, "dllhost.exe" as the process name and the User Name.

Any suggestions / tips are welcome.

Comment: I had this same issue. You should be able to take the code from this question and modify it to your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28839605/checking-windows-user-associated-with-process

Comment: Thanks RianBattle .. I tried to use that function and added the other code in Button click..but doesn't work..